# WindowsServerが固定IPアドレスに設定されている状態で、DHCP DiscoverをWindowsServerが送信する動作を停止する方法

Tags: windows, network, windows-server

ローカルNW環境に設置しているWindowsServer(固定IP)が、約10分間隔でDHCP Discoverパケットを送信し続ける動作に悩んでいます。
なぜIPアドレスが確定しているのにも関わらずDiscoverを送信するのでしょうか？

この動作の原因とDiscoverの送信を停止する方法を教えていただきたいです。

##### 条件 / 環境

- WindowsServer 2022, 2019で同じ動作を確認
- WindowsServer自身にAD、DHCPサーバ機能を設定済み
- ローカルNWでIPアドレスは固定のIPv4アドレス

##### 確認した動作

- 約10分間隔でDiscoverパケットを送信する
  （複数回再送を繰り返してまた10分後に送信が始まる）
- DiscoverのソースIPは0.0.0.0、宛先はリミテッドブローキャスト
- DHCPパケットはDiscoverのみ

Comment: 理由などは Microsoft の中の人でないと答えようがないっス。ここ SO は単にユーザーが集まっているだけのところなので。もしこの件がインシデントであると判断されているなら Microsoft に問い合わせしてください（有料です）。妄想でよければ野良 DHCP Server を無断でこっそり LAN 内部に設置しているユーザーの検出目的とか。

Comment: Windows ServerにはRouge detectionという機能 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941207.aspx というのがあるので、それに関連して検知のために送っていると考えられますが、動作に関する詳しい文献は見つかりませんでした。URLに記載のレジストリを `1` に変更することで動作が変わる可能性がありますが、未確認です。